# How do I share a folder for a Client Machine

Tags: php

I am using windows 7 on server and linux 
RedHat on client, I am in LAN
 i want to share specific folder with specific client,
 what should i do?? please help me.
it gives an error and it shared for all machines .

Comment: Share folder? how? Directory listing or file sharing (smb). Can't really relate php here

Answer (score 0):

right click the folder is to be shared and click sharing in that use advanced sharing option and type evryone there and apply the changes it will be gets shared

Comment: yes, vignesh but i want to give privilages to perticuler users, and which is shared folder is not accessible for other users?? i want this type of facility